# how to consolidate an if-statement with multiple conditions in python 3.8?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I'm trying to take a list of words and print out another list of every word that has all 5 written vowels 'aeiou'.

```
print([word for word in word_list if 'a' in word and 'e' in word and 'i' in word and 'o' in word and 'u' in 
word])
```

For example, 'equation', 'consequential', and 'authorize' would be in the output list.

How can I consolidate all the conditions in the if-statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works :

```
print([word for word in word_list if all(letter in word for letter in "aeiou")])
```

Test [live example on onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/HyXuEZ6qI).

Basically, the conditions follow a pattern so you can factorize them in a test "for each character in the string 'aeiou', test if character is in main string" .

`all(conditions)` is to be used since you want all of them to be true at the same time, because of `and` (for `or` you could use `any` instead of `all`)